# Docker - How to open a debug port for AEM

Tags: apache, debugging, docker, aem

I'm working with Docker to create AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) images on the basis of the following repository https://github.com/AdobeAtAdobe/aem_6-1_docker

I just can't figure out how to open a debug mode for AEM.

I have tried adding a port to EXPOSE `EXPOSE 4502 30311` and adding a start file with the new JVM_OPTS `CQ_JVM_OPTS="-debug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=none -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=30311,server=y,suspend=n ${CQ_JVM_OPTS}"`

and I have also tried changing the START_OPTS `START_OPTS="${START_OPTS} -debug 30311"`

I'm not really comfortable with Docker yet so I'm not sure what I'm missing to startup the debug mode. Do I need to open a port in Docker via `ENV` or `RUN`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to bind your host ports to container ports.

So, in your `docker run` add flag `-p 4502:4502 -p 30311:30311`

Comment: This worked for me thanks, I had to add the ports to the .yml file